# Cabal not building all modules in library

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have this library gsdl.cabal file:

```
cabal-version:  3.6
name:           gsdl
version:        0.0
synopsis:       Global Script source manipulation libraries
homepage:       https://globalscript.org/
author:         Jonathan Cast
copyright:      © Jonathan Cast
maintainer:     Jonathan Cast <jonathanccast@fastmail.fm>
license-file:   PSL
build-type:     Simple
stability:      alpha
extra-source-files: README, COPYRIGHT

library
    build-depends: base
    exposed-modules: GSDL.Core.AST, GSDL.Core.ReadFile
    hs-source-dirs: hslib
```

and this executable gsac.cabal file:

```
cabal-version:  3.6
name:           hsgsac
version:        0.0
synopsis:       A compilation pass for converting Global Script Core code to String Code
author:         Jonathan Cast
copyright:      © Jonathan Cast
maintainer:     Jonathan Cast <jonathanccast@fastmail.fm>
license-file:   PSL
build-type:     Simple
stability:      alpha

executable gsac
    main-is: gsac.hs
    build-depends: base, gsdl
```

I run `cabal sdist -o /home/jcast/globalscript/haskell-packages` in the library source directory, with this output:

```
Wrote tarball sdist to
/home/jcast/globalscript/haskell-packages/gsdl-0.0.tar.gz
```

Then I run `cabal build --config-file=/home/jcast/globalscript/etc/cabal` in the executable source directory, with this output:

```
Build profile: -w ghc-9.0.2 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - gsdl-0.0 (lib) (requires build)
 - hsgsac-0.0 (exe:gsac) (dependency rebuilt)
Configuring library for gsdl-0.0..
Preprocessing library for gsdl-0.0..
Building library for gsdl-0.0..
[1 of 1] Compiling GSDL.Core.ReadFile ( hslib/GSDL/Core/ReadFile.hs, dist/build/GSDL/Core/ReadFile.o, dist/build/GSDL/Core/ReadFile.dyn_o )
Installing library in /home/jcast/.cabal/store/ghc-9.0.2/incoming/new- 2347417/home/jcast/.cabal/store/ghc-9.0.2/gsdl-0.0-1a02d7c4962673481d14d20699037d04906a028286217d00fe9bce8aa1e51dcf/lib
Preprocessing executable 'gsac' for hsgsac-0.0..
Building executable 'gsac' for hsgsac-0.0..
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( gsac.hs, /home/jcast/src/hsgsac/dist-newstyle/build/x86_64-linux/ghc-9.0.2/hsgsac-0.0/x/gsac/build/gsac/gsac-tmp/Main.o )

gsac.hs:3:1: error:
    Could not find module ‘GSDL.Core.AST’
    Use -v (or `:set -v` in ghci) to see a list of the files searched for.
  |
3 | import GSDL.Core.AST (cgsFileCode)
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What? It's only compiling one of the modules in the library. Why?

`/home/jcast/globalscript/etc/cabal` is:

```
repository hackage.haskell.org
    url: http://hackage.haskell.org/

repository globalscript
    url: file+noindex:///home/jcast/globalscript/haskell-packages
```

`ReadFile.hs` is

```
module GSDL.Core.ReadFile (readCoreFile) where

readCoreFile = error "readCoreFile next"

doSomethingElse = error "doSomethingElse next"
```

`AST.hs` is

```
module GSDL.Core.AST (readCoreFile) where

readCoreFile = error "readCoreFile next"

doSomething = error "doSomething next"
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but if you just want to use a local package that is not on Hackage then you can use a cabal.project file (next to `gsac.cabal`):

```
packages: gsac.cabal, ../path/to/gsdl.cabal
```

See the documentation about specifying local packages:

https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cabal-project.html#specifying-the-local-packages

If your package is on GitHub or similar remote version control you can also specify that in the cabal.project file, e.g.:

```
source-repository-package
    type: git
    location: https://github.com/hvr/HsYAML.git
    tag: e70cf0c171c9a586b62b3f75d72f1591e4e6aaa1
```

See https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cabal-project.html#specifying-packages-from-remote-version-control-locations